# Cauchy integral theorem for star-shaped regions vs Cauchy integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't get the point of *Cauchy integral theorem for star-shaped regions*. Doesn't *"normal" Cauchy integral theorem* imply this? Why some books incorporate just *Cauchy integral theorem for star-shaped regions*.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Can you state this mysterious second theorem? In particular what book are you seeing with this in it? If it is what it sounds like, the only reason to have it is for things concerning primitives.

Comment: You can prove different versions of this Theorem. You have to specify the properties of the regions in which the theorem should hold.One of the most basic formulations is the one mentioned above (i know also a homotopy and a homology version).

Comment: The normal one for me is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete, and formally correct proof, requires some fairly delicate topology. If you assume that the domain in star-shaped, most of these topological subtleties disappear.

In other words, it's a lot easier to give a complete proof if we restrict the geometry and topology of the domain. For example, existence of an anti-derivative is easier to do with star-shaped domains. (We only have to consider integrals along line segments.)

Answer (score 1):

In the star-shaped case there is an easier proof. See http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT2410/h14/supplementarynotes/cauchy-starshaped.pdf.